# MYSQL Query: Customer Sales Gap Analysis

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to query 3 tables (Customers, Sales, & Top-Items) and create a list of the top-items that each customer has not purchased.

Relevant fields are

Customers: Customer#
Sales: Invoice#, Customer#, Item#
Top-Items: Item#

Comment: This is not a code-writing or query-writing service.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.`Item#`) AS list_of_top_items_not_purchased
FROM Customers c
CROSS JOIN `Top-Items` t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales s ON c.`Customer#` = s.`Customer#` AND s.`Item#` = t.`Item#`
WHERE s.`Item#` IS NULL
GROUP BY c.`Customer#`;
```

Comment: Downvoter, can you please offer a reason why you think this answer is wrong? Perhaps I can improve it.